# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Error redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Redux gives an error. I can not find a mistake

I can not understand where I made a mistake. before creating redux everything worked.
The error is found in 'header.jsx' line 10:

'let newPosts = props.state.post.map (p => );'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJsLD.jpg)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Error after redux
help me find a bug

'redux-store.js'

```
    import {createStore, combineReducers} from "redux/es/redux";
    import postReducer from "./postReducer";



    let reducers = combineReducers( {
    postPage: postReducer,
    addsPosts: postReducer
    });


    let store = createStore(reducers);

    export default store;
```

'postReducer.js'

```
 let initialState = {

    post:[

        { id: 1, posts: "Hello.Im a development this social networks. Welcome :)" },
        { id: 2, posts: "Yessssss! This start my first page" }

    ],

    postAdd: [
        {messagePost: ""}
    ]
};

export const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD-POST':
            let newPost =
            {
                id: 4,
                posts: action.newMessage
            };
            state.post.push(newPost);
            state.newMessage = '';
            return state;

        case 'UPDATE-POST':
            state.postAdd.messagePost = action.newText;
            return state;
        default: return state;

    }

};


export const addpostCreater = (text) => {
    return { type: 'ADD-POST', newMessage: text }
};

export const updatepostCreater = (text) => {
    return { type: 'UPDATE-POST', newText: text }
};


export default postReducer;
```

'header.jsx'

```
import React from 'react';
import cssmod from './header.module.css';
import Mypost from './../components/mypost';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addpostCreater, updatepostCreater } from "../redux/postReducer";


const Header = (props) => {

    let newPosts = props.state.post.map (p => <Mypost id={p.id} posts={p.posts} />);

    let newpostElement = React.createRef();

    let addPost = () => {
        let text = newpostElement.current.value;

        props.dispatch(addpostCreater(text));
        props.state.postAdd.messagePost = '';

    };

    let newUpdatePost = () => {
        let text = newpostElement.current.value;
        props.dispatch(updatepostCreater(text));
    }; 

...


the page should load
```

Comment: `props.state.postPage.post` should be mapped. You need to first reference the variable postPage from redux-store.js.

Comment: Did you actually call `connect` to receive state updates of your Redux store ([more info](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react))?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment because I'm not 50 rep. But you should never directly modify state rather return a new state. The method state.post.push directly modifies the state try something like a map method call instead in the reducer on the ADD-POST action since it returns a new array.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates you are trying to call .map on something that is not an array. Or at least it's not an array when it's called.